# MYSQL Update table set column equal to SELECT from the same table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `TABLE`:  `|Column1|Column2|`

I need to set `Column1` equal to `(SELECT CONCAT(Column1,'\n',Column2) FROM TABLE)`

Ideas?

Comment: **UPDATE yourTable set Column1 = CONCAT(Column1,'\n',Column2);** . This works for each ROW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `SELECT`, just put the expression in the `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET Column1 = CONCAT(Column1, '\n', Column2)
```